# Post-split, where do I download the Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino-ide

I've been out of the loop with Arduino for several years.  I [heard](http://makezine.com/2015/03/06/arduino-vs-arduino/) about [the split](https://news.slashdot.org/story/16/10/01/1926242/the-arduino-split-is-over-new-non-profit-formed) (another [link](https://olimex.wordpress.com/2015/03/20/arduino-split-in-court-revail-how-the-project-started-and-developed/)), but didn't really understand, nor keep up with it, nor the details of the fallout.

Today, I decided to jump back in and make something, and a [DDG search](https://duckduckgo.com/) led me to [Arduino.cc](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) to get the software.  But is that what I need?

How do I know if that's the right software IDE?  Is there another location?  Does it matter?  Does it depend on more variables?  Is this [split](https://www.howtogeek.com/187663/openoffice-vs.-libreoffice-whats-the-difference-and-which-should-you-use/) akin to the [OpenOffice](https://www.reddit.com/r/software/comments/2tmu4l/openoffice_vs_libreoffice/) and [LibreOffice](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/whats-the-difference-between-libreoffice-and-openoffice/) split, where one is more better (technical term!) supported than the other?

I'm working on an Arduino Uno I got from [Microcenter](http://www.microcenter.com/product/431997/Uno_R3_MainBoard).

Answer (score 3):

The split is already over. They are working on merging everything that happened during the split, if they haven't already.

I'd go with the arduino.cc version, as that was the website before the split (where the other party used arduino.org).

Answer (score 1):

Both sites contain the same version of the IDE. .Org dropped their 1.7.x branch (actually 1.0.x renumbered) and both now have the 1.6.x branch version-bumped up to 1.8.x.

As Gerben noted, the split is over, [The rift is healed!](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2380/4143).